# Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_post()

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm new on wordpress and I'm trying to create my first website, I have an index.php page with about link, which will get about author content from created page (post) inside wordpress dashboard with name about. I'm using [magnific popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) plugin for poups.. I have about.php which includes content of about page like this

> about.php

```
<?php 
        $pageid = 2; // 2 is the id of about page/post
        $about = get_post($pageid);
    ?>

<div id="custom-content" class="white-popup-block" style="max-width:600px; margin: 20px auto;">

    <h3><?php echo $about->post_title; ?></h3>
    <style>
    #custom-content img {max-width: 100%;margin-bottom: 10px;}
    </style>
    <div class="image-container pull-left">
        <img src="<?php echo get_field( "image", $pageid ); ?>">
    </div>
    <h4><?php echo get_field( "brief", $pageid ); ?></h4>
    <p>
    <?php echo get_field( "brief_lines", $pageid ); ?>
    </p>
    <div class="about-content">
        <?php echo $about->post_content; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

> index.php

```
<a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/about.php" class="morelink pull-left text-ajax-popup">read more</a>
```

> footer.php

```
$('.text-ajax-popup').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        alignTop: true,
        overflowY: 'scroll' 
});
```

after click on the link I got this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_post()

Is there files could I include inside about.php ? what is the problem ?

Comment: I don't use wordpress so my advise is very limited but from their doc, https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post, looks like you're trying this on a page not including `wp-includes/post.php or wp-includes/class-wp-atom-server.php``

Comment: I found that, the file wp-blog-header.php should be included @chris85

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not loading WordPress.

You need to build a theme instead of putting PHP files in the root directory. WordPress will setup the environment and then load your theme making functions like `get_post()` available to you without you having to include core files in every PHP file you create.

Take a look at how the default themes are built to get a better understanding of what's involved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to require the "wp-config.php" in PHP files.

```
require_once "wp-config.php";
```

Answer (score -2):

get_post() is not a PHP method.

Use on the next page:

```
function get_post($var){
     return mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}
```

Comment: get_post() is a built in function which included in the functions file of wordpress core, I should include require('wp-blog-header.php'); inside about.php .. thank you for your help